# Java: Send job to server for execution

Tags: java, rmi

I'm looking for a way to execute "jobs" on a remote server. Normally RMI would do just fine but as far as I know, that requires an actual implementation of the logic on the server. My problem is that I can't predefine the jobs on the server because I want them to be as generic as possible.

So what I have in mind is the following: the client has the implementation of a specific job he wants to have executed. This implementation would obviously have to follow a set of rules in order for the server to be able to work with it. The client packs it into an object of some kind, sends it to the server for execution, and waits for the result of whatever computation he asked for.

Is this possible with RMI? If not, is there something else that allows me to work this way?

Thank you for your time and insight.

Comment: Interesting question, the answer really depends on how complex/diverse you want your job specifications to be. Are the jobs simple enough to be defined by a string? Eg `do x to y`, which could be parsed by the server.

Comment: I'm thinking in terms of [`ClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html)

Comment: One important question: can the client code be trusted not to be malicious and/or broken?

Comment: @Close-voter What's off-topic about this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Dynamic code downloading using Java RMI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/codebase.html) but you will have to setup a server to holds clients task classes

Comment: What if each client had its own codebase that it pointed to when talking to the server?

Comment: That should be ok, see section 4.0, never tried it myself, it seems if you set the codebase property on the client the server should use it

Comment: That definitely looks like it could do what I want. I'll have a go at implementing it.
Thanks for the input everyone!

Answer (score 3):

As I unterstand your question the server does not 'know' the code to be executed in advance. 
So what you could try is sending some runtime-interpretable code like groovy, javascript or python and use one of the many interpreters out there on the serverside.

For simpler executions UEL and the concrete JUEL might be worth a look

Comment: Serverside Javascript is a nice idea

Answer (score 0):

Any object that is serializable can be passed over RMI. You could wrap the logic in a serializable object, pass that to the server, and the server executes it (it could have an execute method for example that the server calls).

As mentioned in the comments here, the class you pass from the client to the server would need to be known to both the client and the server.

Comment: To deserialize an object, you need to have the respective class locally. The class definition is not sent.

Comment: That's not how serialization works unfortunately, only field values are serialized, the class definition itself must be present at both ends of the stream.

Comment: Right, the server part of it would need to know about this serializable task class and should use only classes that are present on both ends of the system (client and server).